# How to convert float to NSString with thousand separator and 2 decimal points?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I would like to convert floatvalue to NSString with thousand separator and 2 decimal points but no luck. Attached herewith my code:- Any mistake?

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [_goodPrice floatValue]];
NSLog(@"166 - %@",str); //Result = 900000.00

NSNumber *myNumber = @((int)([_goodPrice floatValue]*100)/100.0);
NSLog(@"169 - %@",myNumber); //Result = 900000

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[_goodPrice floatValue]]];
NSLog(@"Result...%@",numberString);//Result = 900,000. HOW CAN I MAKE IT 900,000.00   ???
```

Comment: Is there not also a property for minimum fraction digits which should then fix your last test? Also I believe you should use currency style instead of decimal in your case. But be careful, these formatters depend on your locale settings unless specified explicitly so some users may experience different results.

Comment: logically you need to use the [`minimumSignificantDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1410174-minimumsignificantdigits?language=objc), perhaps, and also make sure the [`usesSignificantDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1417793-usessignificantdigits?language=objc) it `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""]; //To remove currency symbol
NSLog(@"%@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_goodPrice floatValue]]]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` for you requirement,

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [_goodPrice floatValue]];
NSLog(@"166 - %@",str);

NSNumber *myNumber = @((int)([_goodPrice floatValue]*100)/100.0);
NSLog(@"169 - %@",myNumber);

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[str doubleValue]];
NSLog(@"Result...%@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:num]);
```